# How to provide type-only argument to a function?

Tags: rust

In my short Rust experience I ran into this pattern several times, and I'm not sure if the way I solve it is actually adequate...

Let's assume I have some trait that looks like this:

```
trait Container {
    type Item;
    fn describe_container() -> String;
}
```

And some struct that implements this trait:

```
struct ImAContainerType;
struct ImAnItemType;
impl Container for ImAContainerType {
    type Item = ImAnItemType;
    fn describe_container() -> String { "some container that contains items".to_string() }
}
```

This may be a container that has a knowledge about type of items it contains, like in this example, or, as another example, request which knows what type of response should be returned, etc.

And now I find myself in a situation, when I need to implement a function that takes an item (associated type) and invokes a static function of the container (parent trait). This is the first naive attempt:

```
fn describe_item_container<C: Container>(item: C::Item) -> String {
    C::describe_container()
}
```

This does not compile, because associated types are not injective, and `Item` can have several possible `Container`s, so this whole situation is ambiguous. I need to somehow provide the actual `Container` type, but without providing any container data. I may not have the container data itself at all when I invoke this function!

In search for a solution, I find the documentation for [std::marker::PhantomData](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html). It says:

> PhantomData allows you to describe that a type acts as if it stores a value of type T, even though it does not.

This has to be the Rust's replacement for [Haskell's Proxy type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html), right? Let's try to use it:

```
fn describe_item_container<C: Container>(container: PhantomData<C>, item: C::Item) -> String {
    C::describe_container()
}

let s = describe_item_container(PhantomData::<PhantomData<ImAContainerType>>, ImAnItemType);
println!("{}", s);
```

Compiling... Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::marker::PhantomData<ImAContainerType>: Container` is not satisfied
```

I ask `#rust-beginners` and get a response: `PhantomData` is not meant to be used that way at all! Also I got an advice to simply make a backward associated type link from `Item` to `Container`. Something like this:

```
trait Item {
    type C: Container;
}
fn describe_item_container<I: Item>(item: I) -> String {
    I::C::describe_container()
}
```

It should work, but makes things much more complicated (especially for cases when item can be placed in different container kinds)...

After a lot more experimentation, I do the following change and everything compiles and works correctly:

```
let s = describe_item_container(PhantomData::<ImAContainerType>, ImAnItemType);
println!("{}", s);
```

The change is `::<PhantomData<ImAContainerType>>` to `::<ImAContainerType>`.

[Playground example.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=855b8c837d8e70d2af005be19b811b00&version=stable&backtrace=0)

It works, but now I'm completely confused. Is this the correct way to use `PhantomData`? Why does it work at all? Is there some other, better way to provide type-only argument to a function in Rust?

---

**EDIT:** There is some oversimplification in my example, because in that particular case it would be easier to just invoke `ImAContainerType::describe_container()`. Here is some [more complicated case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e4e0e07ef4125e24f55f40c7f01de55a&version=stable&backtrace=0), when the function actually does something with an `Item`, and still requires container type information.

Comment: *This does not compile* — [seems to compile just fine](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=c98d286832c67299c7506218c391ba40&version=stable). What am I missing?

Comment: @Shepmaster: [This won't compile](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=5255f362bedbf9367e14772b98ee6838&version=stable) if you actually invoke that function from `main()`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right approach; what do you want to achieve? If you need a container with a generic member, why not just have some member `T` and e.g. use [`get_type_id()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html#tymethod.get_type_id) to get its concrete type when needed? Using an associated type doesn't seem like the way to go.

Comment: @ljedrz Associated type gives compile-time guarantees. You are right, it can be checked dynamically during run-time with `get_type_id()`, but I prefer static restriction if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to pass a type argument to a function, you can just do it. You don't have to leave it out to be inferred.

This is how it looks for your second example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3dad589a10c43a66ad08ab051c668e58&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn pack_item<C: Container>(item: C::Item) -> ItemPacket {
    ItemPacket {  
        container_description: C::describe_container(),
        _payload: item.get_payload(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = pack_item::<ImAContainerType>(ImAnItemType);
    println!("{}", s.container_description);
    let s = pack_item::<ImAnotherContainerType>(ImAnItemType);
    println!("{}", s.container_description);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the Rust syntax feature that I missed. It's a bit cumbersome, because if I want to specify one type parameter, I'll have to specify all other, even those that can be inferred by compiler, but it works fine!

Comment: @SergeyMitskevich [actually...](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1d402c2d4a9173b2d0f43886e42c332c&version=stable&backtrace=0)